# Systemverilog function synthesis - automatic vs static

Tags: system-verilog, vlsi, asic

In the context of combinatorial logic synthesis (not simulation):
When should a function be declared as automatic ?
When should a function be declared as static ?

Answer (score 2):

A function should never be declared with a `static` lifetime. There is no case where a function would be automatic by default and need to be explicitly declared static. (and this would be illegal do in a class method anyways).

There are cases where a function must be declared with automatic lifetime so it cn be called recursively and the arguments won't be overwritten.

This is the part of the subject of my DVCon2021 paper "[The Life of a SystemVerilog Variable](https://2021.dvcon.org/sites/dvcon21/files/documents/call-docs/DVCon%20US%202021_Conference%20Program_FINAL-small_0.pdf)".

Comment: "A function should never be declared with a static lifetime." This confuses me a bit. Didn't you suggest (in the link below) to declare the function inside a class as static ?
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/549114/systemverilog-interface-definition-lint-error-message

Comment: A static class method qualifier is not the same as a function with a static lifetime. The static keyword is overloaded.

Comment: I see. thanks for the explanation. I'll re-phrase my main question then: in the context of combinatorial logic synthesis (not simulation) - when should a function be declared with a static method qualifier ? and when with an automatic ?

Comment: https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/what-exact-difference-between-static-tasks/functions-and-automatic-tasks/functions-please-explain-clear-example#reply-44935